# Implementing Tags with ElasticSearch (v1.5.2)

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, tags, nested

Currently i am working with ElasticSearch for indexing and querying of several million documents. Now i want to incorporate tags into these documents as well. And i am not quite sure, what the best way will be, to match my requirements, which are:

I want to query ES for most used tags. Paginating and filtering should be possible as well.

Is this even possible? I've tried using aggregations before and it kind of worked, but i was not able to paginate or filter the results.

```
{
    size: 0,
    aggs: {
        group_by_tags: {
            terms: {
                field: "tags"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, i thought using Nested Objects will be the way to go and i've changed the mapping, which now looks like this:

```
mappings: {
    shop_outfits: {
        _all: {
            enabled: false
        },
        properties: {
            id: {
                type: "string",
                index: "not_analyzed"
            },
            userId: {
                type: "string",
                index: "not_analyzed"
            },
            title: {
                type: "string"
            },
            description: {
                type: "string"
            },
            tags: {
                type: "nested",
                properties: {
                    tag: {
                        type: "string",
                        index: "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            },
            articles: {
                type: "string",
                index: "not_analyzed"
            },
            uniqueId: {
                type: "string",
                index: "not_analyzed"
            },
            createdAt: {
                type: "date",
                format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to return all tags ordered by usage in a list that can be paginated? Or is this simply not possible with Nested Objects?

I am glad for any hint in the right direction!

**EDIT:** 
Or is using a parent/child relationship the right way?

Comment: [Aggregations cannot be paginated (yet)](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915). How many different tags are we talking? Unbounded? Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: Yes. It is up to the users to define the tags. We are normalizing them in the background, so we do not have duplicates with slightly different naming. And want to be able to use an autocomplete feature on the tags.

We are using ES 1.5.2.

Comment: If you're using 1.5.2, make sure to add `"doc_values" : true` to your `tag` field mapping.